# DRF и django_filters. Изменить queryset до применения фильтров

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-filter, queryset

Есть ModelViewSet и FilterSet, которые прекрасно работают. Но проблема в том, что мне нужно преобразовывать queryset до фильтрации, для этого я переопределила метод get_queryset(). Queryset он меняет, но по итогу на странице со списком объектов я вижу, что изменения не произошли.

Если переопределить метод list(), используя в нем переписанный метод get_queryset():

```
queryset = self.get_queryset()
```

Изменения произойдут, но фильтры не будут работать на этом queryset. Я пробовала использовать

```
qs = self.filter_queryset(self.get_queryset())
```

в этом случае фильтры работают, но данные на странице остаются такими, как были до изменений в get_queryset().
Подскажите пожалуйста в чем моя ошибка, почему я не могу отфильтровать queryset c изменениями и что нужно сделать, чтобы фильтрация преобразованного queryset стала возможной?